# Where could I find code to compute Potential Future Exposure

Tags: risk-management, credit-risk, risk-models

Ideally code in SAS, R, Python or Matlab for calculations involving counterparties holding positions in energy markets on multiple price curves, with a Monte-Carlo methodology or a simpified parametric approach?

Comment: You might want to give [QuantLib](https://www.quantlib.org/) a try. It has a Python interface and is able to price a lot of financial products.

Comment: Do you have pricers already and are just looking for something to model the processes?  Or are you looking to start from scratch?

Comment: Thank you Kermittfrog

Comment: I have pricers mathtick andd eventually found some code in GitHub